# 1 to 0..1 Relationship In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I want to create the following relationship. Obviously this is painfully basic but I'm falling at the first hurdle thanks to EF. In my database `SubForm`'s primary key, `Id`, is a foreign key referencing `Application.Id` (enforcing the relationships). When I add a new `Application` EF complains that I don't have a `SubForm_Id` row, I don't want this as this would be obviously be a duplicate of the primary key. Can I add some annotations to the model to sort this out?

[image]

This brings me to another issue, if I want to add a new `Application` with a new `SubForm` to the database at the same time - how could I *get* the `Application Id` (it is defined in the db as an auto-increment int) to set it on the `SubForm` object, or can EF do this for me?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using EF 4.1 with DbContext API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF by convention assumes that your `Application` table has a scalar property `SubForm_Id` when you have a navigational property of type `SubForm`. You need to explicitly configure the Shared Primary Key mapping.

```
public class MyContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Application>()
           .HasOptional(a => a.SubForm)
           .WithRequired(s => s.Application);
    }
 }
```

You can insert both as follows

```
var app = new Application();
var subForm = new SubForm { Application = app };
db.SubForms.Add(subForm);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This has worked, thank-you. I'm assuming it is **not** possible to add the root entity Application and have the SubForm object added as a consequence? If this is correct why is this the case?

Comment: @st3 It may work `var app = new Application { SubForm = new SubForm() };db.Applications.Add(app);`